# How do I make drop down menu from document.getElementById javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make a drop down menu from "menu4" on the code below. The code is running well but I need to introduce a drop down menu. I have tried different ways to have a list inside a list but seems not to work. I really need someones help. Anyone? Thanks.

```js
document.getElementById("nav01").innerHTML =
"<ul id='menu'>" +
"  <li><a href= '#'>Home</a></li>  "  +
"  <li><a href= '#'>menu1</a></li>  " +
"  <li><a href= '#'>menu2</a></li>  " +
" <li><a href = '#'>menu3</a></li> " +
" <li><a href = '#'>menu4</a></li> " +

" <li><a href = 'index.php'> Log Out</a></li> " +
"</ul>";
```

```css
 body {
    font-family: Bookman Old Style;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color:#EBF4FA;
    color: #696969;
    padding-right: 150px;
    padding-left: 150px;
    

}

#top{
     background-color: ;
     height: 120px;
     box-shadow: 10px  #888888;    
}


#main {
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left:  15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    background-color: #EBF4F4;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;
}

h3 {

    font-family: Bookman Old Style;
    border-bottom: 3px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
}

table {
   
    width:100%;
}

table, th , td {
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 0px;
}

th {
    text-align: left;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

ul#menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
    
}

ul#menu li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    line-height:30px;
    max-width:860px;
}

ul#menu li a {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #696969;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}

#footer {
  position: right;
  color: #ffffff;
  
}


h1 {

    border-bottom: 3px solid orange;
    
    font-size: 30px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>About</title>
  <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<nav id="nav01"></nav>   
<body>

<div id="main">
  <h1>About Us</h1>
  <p>Dibon Company Limited is a project delivery and technical consultancy firm that provides efficient and cost effective methodologies  and expertise in managing complex as well as simple projects</p>
  
  <div class="box contactdetails">
      <h2>Our Contact Details </h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Dibon Limited Company</li>
 
        <li class="last">Website: <a href="https://www.dibon.co.ke">dibon</a></li>
        <li>Email: info@dibon</li>
        <li class="last">Facebook: <a href="https://web.facebook.com">Dibon</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: instead of doing this 'manually', how about using the templating feature from a framework, such as angular.js , to generate the dropdown html code from data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you need javascript for this?

If I understand it correctly, you can do this without javascript. Fully functional dropdown menus can take advantage of `hover` states for the links. I went ahead and cleaned up some CSS for ya. Check it out. Here's the key CSS:

```
.navigation-menu li:hover ul {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px ridge #ccc;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 5px 2px #ccc;
  padding:5px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MebwjB

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any js or something else, do it with css3 (transition) by hover:

```css
.mainMenu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: black;
  font-family: Arial;
  line-height: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.mainMenu:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #2f6992;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 150px;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

li:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

.title {
  color: white;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainMenu">
  <span class="title">HOVER MENU-POINT...</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Cheers